# Querying V$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS

Tags: oracle, replication, view, dataguard, archive-log

-- Oracle 19c

when querying v$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS, I get the following output:

```
SELECT DESTINATION, STATUS, ARCHIVED_THREAD#, ARCHIVED_SEQ#,APPLIED_SEQ#,APPLIED_THREAD# FROM V$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS  WHERE STATUS <> 'DEFERRED' AND STATUS <> 'INACTIVE';


DESTINATION     STATUS ARCHIVED_THREAD#    ARCHIVED_SEQ#   APPLIED_THREAD#
/directory/path VALID   1   52089          0               0
dr1             VALID   1   52089          52086           1
dr2             VALID   1   52089          52088           1
dr3             VALID   1   52089          52088           1
```

as shown in the output, the archived_seq# is behind the archived_thread#; however, when I query:

```
SELECT MAX(SEQUENCE#) FROM V$ARCHIVED_LOG WHERE APPLIED='YES';

MAX(SEQUENCE#)

52089
```

on every standby,

the applied archives are the same in the standby's. Why is there a difference in archived_seq# in v$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS?